# Определить наступление нового дня

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

Как запрограммить код - чтобы приложение определяло наступление нового календарного дня?

Задумал так чтобы при наступлении нового дня приложение выполняло определенные действия.
Проковырялся полдня с NSdate - но толи уже глаза не туда смотрят - вобщем не могу реализовать свою задумку  - помогите!

Comment: тема должна звучать так "определение В Objective-c наступление нового дня"

Comment: Я сейчас не имею возможности глянуть подробно вашу задачу, просто советую посмотреть [другой мой ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/251082/objective-c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B0) - там хорошо видно, как можно работать с NSCalendar, NSDataComponents и др.

Comment: Наивное решение - это просто брать календарный день, запоминать его, а потом смотреть сдвиги на единицу. Правда непонятно сходу, как учесть сдвиги между часовыми поясами, но это вроде бы не должно стать помехой, если речь именно о наступлении нового дня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорректируйте меня:

Не критично чтобы считывать секунда в секунду наступление нового дня. 
достаточно просто чтобы когда пользователь запускает приложение - оно сканирует дату и если эта дата больше на день (ну то есть например последний запуск был 6-го, а новый запуск состоялся 8-го) чем та которая была последний раз - то совершает определенные действия

```
calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
today = [NSDate date];
//если это первый запуск - то инициализирую данные следующего дня (tomorrow), с которыми можно будет в дальнейшем сравнивать текущую дату (today)
if (idLanguage == 0) {
    tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tomorrow forKey:@"DateBonus"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

проверяю как соотносится today с tomorrow, если текущий день еще не перешел в категорию "завтра" - то запускаю следующую сцену
if ([today earlierDate:tomorrow]) {
    .....
    .....
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FalseBonusSegue" sender:self];

//если же текущий день уже перескачил границу нового дня, то запускаю блок необходимого действия, заодно устанавливая новые параметры для "завтра"
} else {
    tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tomorrow forKey:@"DateBonus"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self loadBonus];
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: Все верно, Вы сравнивате два таймстампа. Если разница между значениями больше чем 24*60*60 то перезаписываете дату в NSUserDefaults

Comment: Застопорился: currentDay - текущий день (17.10.) nextDay - следующий за currentDay день, при наступлении которого - реализуем действие (17.10.)

         NSDateComponents *componentToday = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDay];
         NSDateComponents *componentTomorrow = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:nextDay];

Но после этого кода xcode мне выдает componentToday - 17 а componentTomorrow - 18 Как так? ЧТО НЕ ТАК?

Хотя после этого NSLog выдает мне что nextDay - 17.10.2013 и далее часы минуты секунды

Comment: Все ок - справился! в итоге разбил дату на компоненты и плюсовал компонент day.
после этого заносил данные наступления нового дня  в NSUserDefaults
и при запуске приложения сравнивал текущую дату и эти данные

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Ваше описание звучит точь-в-точь так, как я предлагал вам в своём первом и втором комментариях. Поздравляю!

Comment: Абсолютно точно )) Пытался велосипед изобрести )) но сейчас есть понимание

Answer (score 0):

NSCalendar -  очень удобный класс, через него можно брать данные сразуже в днях и секундах и минутах, без особого труда.
Ну и так как новый день может начаться через 1 секунду, то можно сравнивать каждую секунду текущий день у NSCalendar. Ну алгоритмов может быть много.

Вот тут [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13860549/887325)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - хранить дату при запросе :) если дата поменялась - значит наступил новый день